# ASP.NET Login Auto Redirects to Default.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, redirect, authentication

So I have a template login system on ASP.NET, and I made it a template so that I could give the button a CssClass. However now when I login, the login works, but it automatically loads defualt.aspx, which I have deleted. What do I need to add in to fix this? I can't find anywhere that would be causing this, but maybe it's something that I'm not doing so it's reverting to default settings. Worse comes to worse, I could recreate default.aspx and add an automatic redirect from there, except that seems like the least ideal.
Login Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/StaticHeader.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="login" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <title>in short. - Login</title>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div class="Absolute-Center">
    <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
        <AnonymousTemplate>
            <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" colspan="2">Log In</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="ctl08$Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="ctl08$Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Text="Remember me next time." />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                            <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                            <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" CssClass="button" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="ctl08$Login1" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>
            </asp:Login>
            <br />
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <a class="button" style="margin-right: 2em;" href="signup.aspx">Register</a>
                <a class="button" href="forgotpassword.aspx">Forgot Password</a>
            </div>
        </AnonymousTemplate>
        <LoggedInTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="logOutLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <br /><br />
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="logOutButton" runat="server" class="button" OnClick="logOutButton_Click">Log Out</asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </LoggedInTemplate>
    </asp:LoginView>
</div>
<style>
    .Absolute-Center {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    }
</style>
</asp:Content>
```

I have also tried setting my default page to home.aspx in the web.config, but that didnt seem to do anything.
Web.config:

```
<configuration>

    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">
        </forms>
      </authentication>
    </system.web>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
    </appSettings>

    //have tried adding this
    <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument>
        <files>
          <clear />
          <add value="home.aspx" />
        </files>
      </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Can we see what you've put in your web config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is:

```
<authentication mode="forms">
<forms loginurl="login.aspx" defaulturl="[page-to-redirect-to].aspx"/>
</authentication>
```